# Why is atan not producing the correct result?

Tags: c, floating-point, trigonometry, radians

I have the following small program which reproduces a trig error in my larger project:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define R2D(trig_fn, val) trig_fn (val * (180.0 / M_PI))

int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", R2D(atan, 2.5));
    return 0;
}
```

The expected result of atan(2.5) converted from radians to degrees is 68.1985..., but instead, this program outputs 1.563815, which is nowhere near the correct answer.

I preprocessed this out to a file; the problem isn't in the macro which was my first guess too; the macro expands properly (`atan (2.5 * (180.0 / 3.14159265358979323846))`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> double atan(double x);
> ```
>
> Returns the principal value of the arc tangent of x, expressed in **radians**.

The output is in radians, not degrees. You need to convert the result of the function to degrees. The input remains a simple unitless number.

```
#define R2D(trig_fn, val) (trig_fn(val) * (180.0 / M_PI))
```

Comment: Correction; it is not true that the input and output are radians. The input to `atan` is not, under the obvious geometric interpretation, a degree measure. Only the output is.